# VDHL - initial value of signal?

Tags: implementation, vhdl, fpga

I have simple VHDL modul that outputs PWM signal. PWM modul has signal that holds current PWM percentage. When I synthesize and implement it, that signal is reset by default to 0. Is there any way to configure it that after implementation PWM percentage is 20 or something else ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to set the power-up default value.  It has to agree with the reset value (if there is one) because the synthesizer will use NOT-gate-pushback to implement it.

Try

```
SIGNAL dutycycle : INTEGER := 20;   -- powerup value

PROCESS (n_reset, clk)
BEGIN
   IF TO_X01(n_reset) = '0' THEN
       dutycycle <= 20;             -- asynchronous reset value
   ELSIF RISING_EDGE(clk) THEN
       dutycycle <= load_dutycycle; -- synchronous load
   END IF;
END PROCESS;
```

Comment: +1 for the example code.
Details will depend on the synthesis tool and the target technology (or FPGA family). Some technologies do not support power-up value. RTM and/or try it our for your specific set-up!

Comment: For future reference; can you provide a pointer to a synthesizer manual with the requirement that reset value and powerup value have to be the same?

Comment: @Philippe: Sure, here it is applied to Altera chips: http://www.altera.com/support/kdb/solutions/rd01072011_91.html

Comment: @BenVoigt: Wow, thanks ! I always thought that default values were only used in simulation. Anyway, this works perfectly, thanks !! P.S. It also works without TO_X01()

Comment: @xx77aBs: `TO_X01` is mostly for simulation.  If you have a weak pull-up resistor on a signal, for example, the simulated values will be `0` and `H` instead of `0` and `1`.  `TO_X01` resolves these and lets you do normal comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

You can put a reset input to your module that loads a default value into your percentage register.

Comment: And what would trigger that reset input ?

Comment: Well, normaly you have a reset input for the whole system (like the reset input in CPUs), my idea was to use this same reset to also resets the PWM module by loading its default value. Don't you have any external reset signal?

Comment: Nop ... Or I don't know that I have. I am using Spartan 3 Starter board if that helps.

Comment: I'm not telling you to do that but once in the past I had a board without an external reset signal, so I made a counter starting from 0 up to 1024, then it sets an output to 1, I used this output as my internal reset signal. Your board, if I not wrong, have a fixed clock of 50MHz, you can use it for some trick like that.

Comment: This: http://www.digilentinc.com/data/products/s3board/s3board_rm.pdf says that you have a reset on pin L14.... I'm not sure... take a look there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that later ... For now I've implemented reset input on my PWM module, and in my Main module I've implemented dummy FSM with two states (powerUp and idle). In powerup it resets PWM module and in idle it loops forever. The most fun part is that it works XD

Comment: @GustavoVargas: You would have a problem if your counter powered up at 1024.  You have to be able to control the powerup value of some register somewhere.